# how to fix light leak from objects?

Tags: modifiers, eevee-render-engine, light, lighting, lightprobe

[image]

[image]

I'm not trolling!I'm really a beginner, the project im current working got a light problem,the light just leak from the glass hood in Eevee,but in another angle,which you can see it from chart 2,the ship hull is still intact,how do i make it completely clamp to each other?(the method i used is create a glass hood separately,then boolean it from the hull,but after i did that the hull is leaking light and the other side still intact)
EDIT:i found the problem is coming from the BG, the BG is a single frame pic, texture coordinated with window with emission, could be emission caused this problem? or the coordinate cant calculate correctly image in view?

Comment: maybe try to enable the Shadows > Contact Shadows of your light?

Comment: thx, it didn't work but after using your method I found the source of the problem, would you mind checking out my edited answer?

Comment: I didn't solve the problem, but I switch to the cycles. the problem source is the glass shader, I can't really fix the problem, but I'm pretty sure because of the glass shader setting.